# How to style checkboxes in Drupal?

Tags: theming

I use the [Better Exposed Filters](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module. I need to style the checkboxes (change the background of the checkbox).

I tried to do with CSS, but it doesn't work. I use jQuery to add a class to the input of the checkbox, and then apply style for this class, but this doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply can’t style a checkbox (+ radio + select) via CSS. You’ll have to include another jQuery plug-in to achieve your goal. Something like [uniformjs](http://uniformjs.com/). Hope this helps and answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an SCSS snippet that I use to style checkboxes & radios w/ CSS only in Drupal:

```
.form-type-checkboxes,
.form-type-radios {
  .form-type-radio,
  .form-type-checkbox {
    position: relative;
    padding: 3px 0;
    input[type="checkbox"],
    input[type="radio"] {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 10;
      opacity: 0;
      vertical-align: middle;
      &, & + label:before,
      &:checked + label:before {
        width: 28px;
        height: 28px;
      }
      &, & + label {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      & + label:before,
      &:checked + label:before {
        border: 1px solid $light-grey;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px $white, 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }
      &:checked + label:before {
        background-color: $orange;
      }
      & + label:before,
      &:checked + label:before {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        display: inline-block;
      }
    }
    input[type="radio"] {
      & + label:before,
      &:checked + label:before {
        border-radius: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If it's an answer to the question. Please add some description